# Executing assembleRelease Gradle task does now work from custom task

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have the following Gradle task defined in my build.gradle file

```
task myTask() << {
    println "Start"
    assembleRelease.execute()
    println "end"
}
```

What I want is to execute `assembleRelease` gradle task when I execute `myTask`.
However, what I get is the following output

```
Executing tasks: [myTask]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Relying on packaging to define the extension of the main artifact has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0
:gymgym:myTask
Start
end

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

As you can see, "Start" is followed by "end", meaning that `assembleRelease` has not been invoked.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Each task in Gradle is node on a DAG. It sounds like you're trying to surround one task with another, which doesn't fit the model. You can, however, append work to the beginning and/or end of any task using `doFirst` and `doLast`. If you want it to be optional, you can make it depend on an optional command line argument.

```
ext.SHOULD_WRAP = hasProperty('shouldWrap') ? shouldWrap.toBoolean() : false
if (SHOULD_WRAP) {
    wrapAssemble()
}
def start() {
    println "Start"
}
def end() {
    println "end"
}
def wrapAssemble() {
    assembleRelease.doFirst {
        start()
    }
    assembleRelease.doLast {
        end()
    }
}
```

With this configuration, calling `./gradlew assembleRelease -PshouldWrap=true` will execute the assemble task with your prepended and appended work. Calling `./gradlew assembleRelease -PshouldWrap=false` or simple `./gradlew assembleRelease` will execute the assemble task normally.

*Old answer*

<s>Just set your task as a dependency for assembleRelease:</s>

task myTask() << {
    println "Start"
    println "end"
}
assembleRelease.dependsOn "myTask"

Now your task will always be executed when assembleRelease is.

Comment: But how can I execute my code _before_ and _after_ assembleRelease is invoked? In your answer, myTask will fire up only before.

Comment: See the updated answer for a way to accomplish this.

Comment: Thanks, looks close to what I expected. But not always I would like to invoke _start_ and _end_ tasks when I run _assembleRelease_. In some cases I would just want to run _assembleRelease_ without any of my additions. Is there a way to achieve that too?

Comment: Thanks, though it looks not very neat, I suppose it's the only way to handle that.

Comment: I have to admin that the proposed solution does not work, doFirst and doLast are never called.